# Using XPath count() with contains()

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working with the following (suboptimal) XML:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:2 Y:0</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:2 Y:0</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I am trying to use XPath to count the number of `<c>` nodes whose contents contain `X:1`:

```
count(contains(/a/b/c, 'X:1'))
```

However, this returns an error rather than returning the expected count of `3`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is one of those cases where I'd be inclined to suggest preprocessing your XML with a stylesheet that expands these elements to `<c><X>1</X><Y>0</Y></c>` etc., then processing data like this becomes trivial. If this is just a once-off task then this probably isn't worthwhile, but if it's something you'll have to do a lot, it's definitely worthwhile considering getting the data into a more usable form first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That isn't how you use `contains()`. Try

```
count(/a/b/c[contains(., 'X:1')])
```

Comment: @gjb, @Phil More like: "This isn't how you use `count()`" since the problem was that `count()` takes a node set as a parameter but `contains()` returns a boolean value.

Comment: @jasso `contains()` expects argument one to be a string, not a node set so there was really two problems

Comment: @Phil Well actually also in your example the first argument of `contains()` is a node-set. The major point here is that XPath spec explicitly states that arguments are converted to the type required by the function and that it is an error if an argument cannot be converted to the required type. `contains()` succeeds but `count()` fails because an argument that is not of type node-set cannot be converted to a node-set.

Comment: Interesting... when I run that `count(...)` command against the sample data from OP, I get `3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3`

Answer (score 3):

**Probably a little bit more efficient** (if the property exhibited in the provided XML document isn't accidental):

```
count(/a/b/c[starts-with(., 'X:1')])
```

Comment: +1 for your suggestion, but I'm afraid that the ordering may sometimes vary.

Comment: @gjb: If so, it is good to provide a better XML example, showing this in fact.