# Seeking the correct xpath to count elements

Tags: selenium, xpath, graph

I use selenium for a task and I try to count a list of elements of in kibana's graph.

the doc is like that

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
  <div class="chart">
    <svg height="454" width="2031">
      <g clip-path="url(#chart-area256)" transform="translate(0,10)">
        <clipPath id="chart-area256"><rect height="439" width="2031" y="0" x="0"></rect>
          </clipPath>
            <g class="pathgroup 0"><path d="...."></path></g>
            <g class="pathgroup 1"><path d=""></path></g>
            <g class="pathgroup 2"><path d=""></path></g>

          <g class="points area">
            ...</g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

I query for all g or for all @class="pathgroup"

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//g')))
```

and

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//g[@class="pathgroup"]')))
```

Both return zero elements for some reason. So I tried other queries as well

```
len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="chart"]'))
```

//div[@class="chart"] looks to work. with devtools returns svg which is right. But when I try

```
$x('//div[@class="chart"]/svg').length #devtools  command
```

returns zero again. Although

```
$x('//div[@class="chart"]/*').length #devtools  command
```

returns the correct value

I just wonder why and how! any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513691/using-xpath-count-with-contains ?

Comment: are you using the right xpath? how are you getting it?

Comment: @fabersky yeah Its the right xpath. for now I use '//div[@class="chart"]/*/*/* to get all the elements of my interest. But this is not efficient and try to understand why if i use the actual tags in the path doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

`len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//g[@class="pathgroup"]'))` will return empty list as there are no such class as "pathgroup" on page, but "pathgroup 0", "pathgroup 1"... You need to implement following code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[name()="g" and starts-with(@class, "pathgroup")]')
```

Try and let me know if this work or not

Comment: i gave a go with devtools. it doesnt seem to work. it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath has a `count` function try this-

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("count(//div[@class='chart-wrapper']//g)")
```

Comment: Very sorry for the late response. I gave a try but it didnt work. Also I tried to play around with that but without any luck!

Comment: Try `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("count(//div[@class='chart']//g[@class='pathgroup'])")`

Comment: testing again on devtools on Firefox $x("count(//div[@class='chart']//g[@class='pathgroup'])"). returns "TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type."

Comment: Could post the website url and tell what you wanna grab?

Comment: you dont need any specif site to run code against. On Kibana try to create a pie chart and go through the code that is generated for this chart. My main objective was to count the elements of the graph. I am pretty sure what you have suggested so far should have worked. So I wonder if there is something that I dont get it.